# Crystal Report Developer Version is not compatible with Visual Studio 2012 Express,which Crystal Report version to install?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I installed Crystal Report from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 support pack 8 with visual studio 2012 express edition,but it didn't work as in documentation it is clearly stated that it is only compatible with Visual Studio professional edition.(Which i got after spending few hours)

My question is : which version of crystal report will be compatible with Visual Studio 2012 Express edition?
Plz reply...
Regards,
Sumit